# I am getting an issue to integrate cognito signup

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-cognito

com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentityprovider.model.InvalidParameterException: App client 45f45bitpl1u3n2pku8fm0r3im is not configured for secret but secret hash was received (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentityProvider; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: e0af537f-a973-49c2-afa6-7c629fade1fd)

Comment: For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We're gonna need a little more context. "Integrate cognito signup" can mean a number of things. What library are you using? What are you trying to do?